# In subversion I want to Revert back to a revison then step through each revision to see where it broke

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

My project broke somewhere in the past 25 revisions. I need to isolate the file causing the problem, and would like to find the revision where the problem was introduced.

I was thinking of using `svn update  -r 404` and then each one after that `405,406 ... etc`

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do it binary style. Go to the 12th/13th revision. Broken? Go to the 6th revision. Broken? Go to the 3rd revision. Not broken? It's the 4th or 5th!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using the git-svn bridge (git is excellent for quick local branching) and using git bisect to quickly find the revision that broke it.

Comment: yeah i figured it be easier with git.. I dont really like svn, but idk if I'd have access to that at work...

Comment: I didn't realize we have git installed, I'm trying this, i love git much more than subversion.

Comment: @loosecannon - you should go ahead and mark this as answer then.

Comment: @manojids was waiting to get it working first, all these answers were so helpful!

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised people haven't mentioned [svn-bisect](http://search.cpan.org/~infinoid/App-SVN-Bisect-1.1/bin/svn-bisect)

```
$ svn-bisect --min 404 --max 429 start
$ svn-bisect bad
$ svn-bisect bad
$ svn-bisect good
[etc etc]
$ svn-bisect reset
```

Comment: is svn-bisect a 3rd part tool, or is it packaged with subversion?

Comment: It's a separate tool. I already included a link in my answer, but did not realise that the link highlight is very subtle.  svn-bisect is a perl app available via CPAN and github.

Comment: yeah i found it. I downloaded it but had trouble getting it to work in my home dir. I realized I have git installed so I'm trying to use git-svn and git bisect, idk why i didn't do that a while ago. But this bisect thing is cool..

Comment: @Henk Langeveld Are you saying you already mentioned this in your answer? Because I had posted 16 hours before you,

Comment: Hi manojlds, the comment above specifically answers the question about the origin of svn-bisect.  Both of us included links implying svn-bisect is a separate tool, but the problem with SO is that links are hard to see.

Answer (score 1):

[svn-bisect](https://github.com/Infinoid/svn-bisect/) also allows you to automate the search if you can supply a command for the bug you're looking for:

$ svn-bisect run 'command [arg ...]'

To speed up the search I would recommend to clone the svn repository into a local git or hg repository, and run the bisect from there.  Both support bisect automation:

$ hg bisect -c 'cmd ...'

or

$ git bisect run '...'